# c++ remove items from vector whose values are within an interval

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Is there a convenient way to remove items from a vector (or another stl container) whose values are within an certain interval?

So for example: I got an vector with float values

```
1.1 1.3 2.2 3.2 4.1 5.2 5.1 1.1 8.0 2.1
```

and a delta of 0.2, which should lead to the following result

```
1.1 2.2 3.2 4.1 5.1 8.0
```

thus removing all "duplicate" items within the delta and keep one of the values within the range.
It can be assumed that the values are "clustered", where the difference between these is more than 3*delta. Only one value (the mean) of the cluster should be kept, all the others from the cluster should be removed.

For sure, it is possible to iterate with nested loops, but this seems quite complicated, because of the changing iterators, so I thought of a more convenient way. I found remove_if for example, but this function cannot "compare".

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Righ, from my example it should be the median, but anyway I calculate the mean afterwards for interpolation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `std::unique` with a predicate:

```
template <typename It, typename Predicate>
It unique(It first, It last, Predicate pred);
```

The most used form of `std::unique` takes no predicate and just removes duplicates from a sequence. But you can write one that implements your filter (in your case, compares two values using a gap) and you are set. Something like:

```
bool CompareWithGap(double a, double b)
{
  return abs(a - b) <= 0.2;
}
```

And use it to call `std::unique`:

```
auto it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), CompareWithGap);
```

Where `v` is your vector (or any other sequence).

EDIT: Forgot to mention that you need to sort your sequence before using `std::unique`. If this is not an option, you have to write your own algorithm.

2nd EDIT: For completion, as pointed out by Christian Rau in his comment, you can now erase the items removed from your sequence by using the `erase` method in it:

```
v.erase(it, v.end());
```

Comment: Probably paired with `std::vector::erase`.

Comment: @ChristianRau To remove the useless trail, indeed.

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique, using `std::unique` with a non-equivalence relation is undefined behavior. `CompareWithGap` is not transitive and therefore no equivalence relation.

Comment: @chw That's true, but OP says that we can assume that values are clustered. In this case, the relation is indeed an equivalence relation. The indefinition in this case would only be that we would not know which value would be kept in each cluster, but I assume that this is not important.

Answer (score 6):

You question is actually quite complicated because 'one of the values within the range' is not well defined. For instance given

1.1 1.2 1.3

which do you want to keep? Presumably the *first one*, i.e. 1.1. OK now how about

0.9 1.1 1.3

Following the first one rule, we keep 0.9 and 1.3, But we could have kept just 1.1 instead. The question I think is are 0.9 and 1.3 'duplicates' or not? I don't think you've defined this well enough.

What about this case, 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6? All values are within 0.2 of one other value but not all are within 0.2 of every other value. So are they all duplicates? Or do you need to split them up? If so how should they be split up, pick 1.1 and 1.4 perhaps?

So I think until you define your problem a bit more precisely it's not really possible for you to write the code or for us to help you.

You might want to look at the [disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Depending on precisely what you are trying to do it may be the most efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my description. It can be assumed that the values are clustered, so the case 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 should not appear, only for example 1.1 1.12 1.0 1.13 1.14 2.0 2.1 2.15 2.16

Comment: Well, a disjoint-set data structure would indeed work, but the I could also use pattern recognition algorithms, e.g. mean-shift, but this is quite an overkill for this application. I would prefer a simple stl container based approach

Comment: I totally agree with you, but keep in mind that this is more of a comment than an answer, even if it probably won't fit that well into the confined space of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a new vector while iterating the existing one and populating with the desired data? You can then remove the old vector and return a reference to the new vector.

Comment: Such a proper functional approach is certainly a good idea, but "You can ... return a reference to the new vector" is wrong, you must return new objects by value (or by smart pointer). What you probably mean is to exchange the result with the input in the end, and then just let the temporary result leave scope.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to keep the first item (thus if you have 0.9, 1.1 and 1.3 you keep 0.9 and 1.3) then your predicate should be a class.

Ideally your class should look something like this:

```
class IsWithinRange
{
   std::set< double > values;
   double tolerance;

public:
   explicit IsWithinRange( double tol ) : tolerance( tol )
   {
   }

   bool operator()( double val )
   {
       std::set< double >::iterator iter = values.lower_bound( val );
       if( iter != values.end() )
       {
           if( *iter - val < tolerance )
           {
              return false;
           }
       }
       if( iter != values.begin() )
       {
          --iter;
          if( val - *iter < tolerance )
          {
              return false;
          }
       }
       values.insert( val );
       return true;
    }
};
```

That should work as a functor predicate class for `std::remove_if` but it may copy the internal std::set more times than you would like it to so you can try to "optimise" that if you feel you need to. (Create it with the set although that's rather intrusive and you can also specify the 3rd template parameter of remove_if to indicate a reference rather than rely on deduction). Note that the predicate operator() is non-const.